# Xcode loading AppDelegate from another target

Tags: xcode

I create two targets. Xcode creates two files called `AppDelegate.h` and two files called `AppDelegate.m`. It puts every pair in different directories. I compile the first target, it works fine. I choose the second target. I compile, it uses the `AppDelegate.h` from the first target.

Is there a way to solve that without having to rename the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a xcode limitation/bug.

The best solution for this without causing major chaos is to add the full absolute path to your `#import` line... so, instead of

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

use

```
#import "/asolute-pat-to-appdelegate1/AppDelegate.h"

#import "/asolute-pat-to-appdelegate2/AppDelegate.h"
```

etc.